# convert time UTC("09:18:00.000+05:00") time to local (9:18)

Tags: angular

Can any buddy help to convert "09:18:00.000+05:00" to "9:18" in angular
here is my code

```
                this.endTime =result.standardShift.endTime.toISOTime().;
                this.startTime =result.standardShift.endTime.toISOTime()
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const nowDate = new Date(Date.now()); 
const showTime = nowDate.toLocaleTimeString(
   navigator.language,
   {
     hour12: false,
     hour: '2-digit',
     minute: '2-digit'
   }
);
console.log(showTime);
```